# Java sum of multiples in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I wrote the following code to get all of the numbers from 0 to 1000 that are multiples of three:

```
public class Hi {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
        if(i % 3 == 0)
          System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

Now I would like to add these numbers together and print the result after the loop.

Answer (score 5):

No need to test for multiplicity of 3 if you iterate by multiples of 3. Finally, to add numbers you should be performing arithmetic. Something like,

```
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 3; i < 1000; i += 3) {
    sum += i;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Or, in Java 8+, using an `IntStream` (for the same result) like

```
System.out.println(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000 / 3).map(i -> i * 3).sum());
```

Answer (score 1):

....And because we all will need java-8 and lambdas oneday...

```
final List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 2, 2 }));
final int sum = myList.stream().filter((i) -> i.intValue() % 3 == 0).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
System.out.println("Sum of divisible by 3 is " + sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you go through the numbers from 1 to 1000, you can add the multiple of 3 to a list. Then, you could go through that list, and add each number in that list to a sum.

```
public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] multiples = new int[1000]; // default initialized with zeroes
        mIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++) {
            if(i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                multiples[mIndex] = i;
                mIndex++;
            }
        }

        int sum2 = 0;
        for(int i2 = 0; i2<mIndex; i2++)
            sum2 += multiples[i2];

        System.out.println(sum2);
    }
}
```

But that involves going through the numbers twice, and creating another list. It's simpler and more efficient to add the multiple of 3 to a sum as you go from 1 to 1000.

```
public class Hi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
            if(i % 3 == 0) sum += i;

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Edit: As the other poster said, there are smarter ways to do this. There are also math formulas for getting this sum in O(1).